# How do i figure out why and where is the connectivity problem?

Tags: networking

There is a website [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

It hits an API.

Say its URL is `www.example.com/backend/v1/path/to/what/i/want`

Now, in turn this URL calls another api.

```
https://www.universalapi.com
```

Many clients use the same api, that is why it's called `universalapi`.

For example, `example2.com` will also call the same API after getting redirected from its backend like what happened above.

The response from the server is coming very slow and sometimes don't even come. As per the logs the response seems to come from universalapi.com.

```
2024-02-14 13:17:58 [blablathread]    ERROR a.b.c.d.e.RestNxTemplate:81 - Error response : I/O error on POST request for  "https://universalapi.com/this/is/what/i/want": Read timed out; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read timed out
2024-02-14 13:17:58 [blablathread]   ERROR a.b.c.d.e.RestNxTemplate:83 - Error log :
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://universalapi.com/this/is/what/i/want": Read timed out; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read timed out
```

Sometimes it also gives the correct response which is the data from the api. But sometimes it is slow and that's what I need to investigate along with why I am getting read timeout, where's the actual problem?

The thing is universalapi is being hit by various clients as stated earlier and all of them are able to display the output.
It suggests the server example.com is not able to handle the request. But any ways to actually prove this?

Load testing comes to my mind. Not sure how I'd be able to do that though as I don't have QA expertise.

How'd you tune this server?

I tried to

1. Send a curl POST Request to universalapi as normal curl wasn't accepted.

   curl: (35) TCP connection reset by peer
2. ping universalapi
   ping gave the ip but it is not pingable. Most likely the ping is disabled on the remote server.
3. telnet is working in that IP at port 443, but that doesn't give the variable of interest for me. Which is the time required to get response from the server. As I am trying to figure that out.

Comment: If you control any of the servers involved, what do the logs say?  If you do not control the servers, there would be too many unknown variables to make suggestions as to the root cause (maybe they throttle requests and responses or have otherwise blocked your access).  You should be able to use the developers tools of your browser to track load times and test the responses of all the websites involved.  Your `nested exception` errors could indicate there are more errors than what you have currently posted.

Comment: I control the servers. I'll immediately contact devs on what this error mean. Any gidance to troubleshoot this issue (any more I mean).